# Use getIntent() and getPackageInfo in DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm creating a Dialog showing the permissions required by a specific application. The problem is that I can not use getIntent () and getPackageInfo in a class that does not extend Activity, so how can I do? The code is this.

```
public class DialogPermissions extends DialogFragment{

    public android.app.Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        String value2;
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_permissions, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        TextView permissions = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.permissions);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null) {
        value2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("packageApplication");
        }

        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageInfo(value2, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

            String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
            if ( requestedPermissions != null ) {
                for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
                }

            }
        }
        catch ( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        builder.setTitle("Permission")
               .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       dismiss();
}
               });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it like this-

```
Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();
```

and-

```
getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, flags)
```